# How to investigate why a PHP page redirect is not working?

Tags: php, redirect

Does anybody have any ideas why the below page isn't redirecting?

My php file that I want to redirecting is:

```
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
} else {
redirect_to("new_subject.php");
}
?>
```

The functions file is:

```
<?php 
function redirect_url($new_location)
{
  header("location:".$new_location);
  exit;
}
?>
```

I have removed the db_connection.php file to see if that makes any difference but it doesn't.

Comment: Your function name is actually `redirect_url()`, but in your code you're calling the (undefined) function `redirect_to()`. Do I get a cookie?

Comment: Doh! thanks - didn't spot that! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function name is `redirect_url()`

So code should be

```
else {
redirect_url("new_subject.php");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that the function you call and the function name you have are different ("redirect_to" vs. "redirect_url"), you also have white space before you make a header call.  The space between the requires and the next PHP block is white space and will disallow setting of headers after the white space has been sent to browser.

I would highly suggest you turn on error logging in PHP and reference the error logs when investigating a problem.  You would see both the function call error and the header error in your logs.

Also, it is generally pretty poor coding form to open and close PHP tags unnecessarily.  You could clean this up to look like this:

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/db_connection.php");
require_once("../includes/functions.php");

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    redirect_url("new_subject.php");
}
?>
```

Note here that you can keep a separation between the requires and the code to aid in readability, but since you never exit the PHP block, you don't have a white space problem.

Comment: Thanks that has fixed the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your function call should be

```
redirect_url("new_subject.php");
```

instead of

```
redirect_to("new_subject.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this,

```
    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            //some thing do here
          } else {
                redirect_url("new_subject.php");
        }

        function redirect_url($new_location)
        {
            header("location:".$new_location);
            exit;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the white space problem, and in fact adds duplicate function (with different name) to the code base.  The function should just be referenced correctly, not copied to a new location with a different name.